# Queries with Multiple Constraints

Tags: sql

I have the following tables and fields:

```
+------------------+  +-------------------+  +---------------+
| Request          |  | RequestItem       |  | Item          |
+------------------+  +-------------------+  +---------------+
| + Requester_Name |  | + Request_No      |  | + Item        |
+------------------+  +-------------------+  +---------------+
| + Request_No     |  | + Item            |
+------------------+  +-------------------+
```

I would like to filter the items which are selected under a particular request number, along with a specific requester name. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Flag as offensive -- offensive to my eyes.

Comment: @Coronatus: Please give ANITHA some reasons why you don't like it.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Look at the revision log

Comment: @Coronatus. Yeah, fair point. Didn't see that. But still.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492184/many-to-many-relations-in-rdbms-databases-mysql

Answer (score 1):

In SQL? Of course I haven't tested this, but what about:

```
SELECT items
FROM item INNER JOIN requestitem ON item.items = requestitem.item
WHERE requestitem.request_no = Whatever_Request_Number_You_Want
```

Or how about:

```
SELECT items
FROM item INNER JOIN requestitem ON item.items = requestitem.item
INNER JOIN request ON requestitem.request_no = request.request_no
WHERE request.requester_name = 'Whatever_Name_You_Want'
```

Comment: Note: Field name (and table name) is "item", not "items" in the original question.

Comment: Yeah but from the **first** revision of the original question: "UNDER ITEM TABLE I HAVE A FIELD CALLED ITEMS"; http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/161f51f2-1404-4495-9865-8daa49a7ce64/view-source

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions about what the data looks like, but here's a try:

```
SELECT item
FROM requestitem
    JOIN item ON requestitem.item = item.item
    JOIN request ON requestitem.request_no = request.request_no
WHERE
    request.request_no = 8642
    AND request.requester_name = 'Specific J. Requester';
```