# How do I relate multiple rows in two tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

table1:

```
id(int) | stuff(text)
-------------------------
1       | foobarfoobarfoo
2       | blahfooblah
3       | foo
```

table2:

```
id(int) | otherstuff(text)
--------------------------
1       | foo
2       | bar
3       | blah
```

A row in table1 can have more than one of foo, bar etc.  And, each row in table2 can appear in more than one row of table1.

Which is a better way of keeping this straight.  Should I create a third table like this:

table3:

```
id_from2(int) | id_from1(int)
-----------------------------
1             | 1
1             | 2
1             | 3
2             | 1
3             | 2
```

Or, should I have an column of type array added to table1 and table2 to keep track of the same information?

Comment: Depends on your database system and data model, but most likely creating an intermediary table will be the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using *junction tables* is the correct way of implementing many-to-many relations in RDBMS.

You can add more attributes to your junction table (i.e. `table3`) if necessary. For example, if the relations are *ordered*, you can add a third field that specifies an ordering of the `(table1, table2)` combinations. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2492349/335858) to an answer on Stack Overflow that gives a nice detailed example of a many-to-many table.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard [Many-To-Many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) design, most flexible solution would be a third table with id associations as you shown.

Answer (score 1):

Can't agree more. Your design of adding a third table is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Relation table is the best way to relate many-to-many relationships. You did it well.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a many to many relationship? One from table 1 can have relation to more objects in 2, and the other way around? Yes, use a third table like you said, it's a best practice. Also attach a primary key autoincrement column, just to be safe

Comment: @Shedal in case he grows a high-level application he can use this key to index (address) a relation, in case he wants to build somethin on it - e.g. add meta info on the relation that does not fit in a field (column). I think this is a pattern used by ORM for any model.

Comment: Can't he just create a key field once he needs it?

Comment: You are right, just tested, mysql would auto-populate it with increments and build the index.